# quick [php function] -> [javascript function] question

Tags: php, javascript

if anyone fancies doing me a really quick favour, it would be really appreciated:

```
static function make_url_safe($z){
    $z = strtolower($z);
    $z = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s] /i', '', $z);
    $z = str_ireplace(' ', '-', $z);
    return $z;
}
```

what js functions should i be looking at to convert this function to javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var s = 'Abc- sdf%$987234'.toLowerCase();
s.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]+/g, '').replace(/ /g, '-');
```

It's not an *exact* equivalent, because your original function makes little sense: using `i` flag after converting string to lower case, using `a-zA-Z` with `i` flag on lower-case string, random space after the character class, `str_ireplace` with space as a first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Not equivalent, but has the same goal of making strings URL safe:
[`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURI) or [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: i need to make an __exact equivalent__. So rather than using a built in url encoding function i need to use some smaller native js functions like .replace(), combined to make my make_urol_safe() function

Comment: In that case, go with @SilentGhosts answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String) and [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
function makeURLSafe(z){
    return z.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]+/g, '').replace(/ /g, '-');
}
```